# Oracle: Java: Force “select … for update” to not return until a match is found

Tags: java, oracle, select

I have a table that I want its records to be picked sequentially, processed only once and then deleted. There are multiple instances of the application that are running. The table has a timestamp that is used for sorting in ascending order.

The table cannot be locked because it is being written to by triggers, only the record being processed can be locked.

I use the following SQL command: “select a.time_stamp, a.entity_type, a.action, a.entity_keys from MyAudit a  order by time_stamp asc for update”

And the following code snippet to run the query:

```
connection.setTransactionIsolation( Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE );
connection.setAutoCommit( false );
statement = connection.prepareStatement( GetFirstAudit, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
statement.setMaxRows( 1 );
//statement.setQueryTimeout( 10 ); // This has no effect
results = statement.executeQuery();
if ( false == results.next() ) {
// Close connection, sleep and loop back
} else {
  // Process the record
  results.deleteRow();
  results.close();
  connection.commit();
}
```

If there are no records in MyAudit table the query returns right away. Is there a way to force it to sit there until a record shows up rather than sleeping and looping?

BTW, "where rownum=1" causes deleteRow() to fail and exceptions to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have the inserting entity under your control, so that you could use a JMS queue from the insertion to your processing application, I see no way how to inform your code of the insert in a non-polling way using pure Java.

But Oracle supports Java triggers, as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call2.htm

Basically, you define a trigger to be written in Java:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_sal (
  emp_id NUMBER, old_sal NUMBER, new_sal NUMBER)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'DBTrigger.logSal(int, float, float)';
```

In this trigger method, you can now enqueue the row to be processed in a JMS queue. This way, you will not poll the database, but be informed on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force it to sit there until a record shows up rather than sleeping and looping?

No there isn't.

Think about it? How would it be implemented? Would the dbserver watch every update to the table and check if the update can satisfy the query?

What you are looking for is online algorithm/stream processing, not query processing.

Comment: More importantly, depending on transaction isolation level, you won't even see anything until you start another transaction, so the statement simply cannot see "new" records.

Comment: Not sure if that is more important but it does underline the fact that sql queries are results as of some point-in-time

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I just wanted to make sure that there is not a different approach that I have not considered. The implementation works as is. FYI, I am using triggers already for writing records into this table. And I considered using JMS (I have used ActiveMQ in previous apps) but the added complexity is not worth it. Cheers.